# Linksys E2500 works as access point

Tags: wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I have 2 wireless routers: a Belkin ADSL router where I receive the internet from ISP via cable, and a Linksys E2500. Is there any way that I can make the Linksys router an access point? Or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Most wifi-routers can be used as just an access-point. (Not all. You will have to try to see if yours can do it.)

Basically you connect 1 of the LAN ports of the E2500 to a LAN port of the Belkin.
Leave the WAN/uplink port of the E2500 **NOT** connected.
In the E2500 you have to disable DHCP because the Belkin is already handling that. And for various reasons (DNS mainly) with consumer-equipment in most cases that is best done by the internet-facing router.
Configure the WIFI of the E2500 as usual.
If the Belkin also has Wifi it is probable best to have them BOTH setup for the same SSID and same password and configure them both to use the same channel(s). That way your client-devices will automatically pick the one with the strongest signal and will mostly smoothly roam from one AP to the other when you move through the building.

Please note: In some equipment you can't disable DHCP, or the device won't work if the WAN connection is not used. In that case you will have to daisy-chain like Moses proposed in his answer.

Comment: It is generally preferable to configure them on different channels. Devices will still automatically pick the strongest signal and smoothly roam.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be very simple.

Simply plug an ethernet cable from a LAN port on your Belkin ADSL router to the WAN (Internet) port on the E2500.

The default settings for WAN/LAN should be fine on the router, and all you need to do is set up the WiFi.

Comment: You should configure a static LAN IP address in the router. That address should be inside the other router's LAN range but outside its DHCP range. So, for example, if the LAN is 192.168.1.0/24, the other router's LAN IP address is 192.168.1.1, and the other router's DHCP range is .100 to .200, then you could configure 192.168.1.2 as the router's LAN IP address. You could then access it using that IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this that you want to achieve?

On the second router if you setup DHCP but for the gateway put in the first routers IP address. And for the second router the IP address should be assigned statically with the first router as the gateway. That should work